# How to set local variable in CASE and the result is concatenate along the query value?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
DECLARE @strSpeaker varchar(90)
SET @strSpeaker = ''

SELECT 
    [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE], [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_DESC], 
    CASE 
       WHEN [EVENT_PIC].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE] 
          THEN @strSpeaker += [USER_MASTER].[USR_ID] ',' 
          ELSE NULL 
    END 
FROM 
    [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_MASTER]
LEFT JOIN 
    [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_PIC] ON [EVENT_PIC].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE]
LEFT JOIN 
    [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_SPEAKER] ON [EVENT_SPEAKER].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE]
LEFT JOIN 
    [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[USER_MASTER] ON [USER_MASTER].[USR_REFCODE] = [EVENT_PIC].[USR_REFCODE]
LEFT JOIN 
    [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[PARTICIPANT_MASTER] ON [PARTICIPANT_MASTER].[PCPT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_SPEAKER].[PCPT_REFCODE]
```

It returns a syntax error on '=' and I also try to query and directly set the value  but it just return one single value.

Comment: Please format your code along with an explaination of what you tried and whats not working.

Comment: oh sorry, I already amend it..

Comment: Is your goal to end up with a single value in `@strSpeaker`, or a comma-delimited list of values?

Comment: yes my goal to get return comma-delimeted list

Comment: i think you are looking for a `stuff for xml path` function

Comment: ok but it not possible to do with this above query?

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the value within the statement like that, it needs to be returned like this:

```
DECLARE @strSpeaker varchar(90)

SET @strSpeaker = ''

SELECT @strSpeaker = CASE WHEN [EVENT_PIC].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE] THEN [USER_MASTER].[USR_ID]  
   ELSE NULL END 

FROM [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_MASTER]

LEFT JOIN [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_PIC] ON [EVENT_PIC].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE]

LEFT JOIN [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[EVENT_SPEAKER] ON [EVENT_SPEAKER].[EVT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_MASTER].[EVT_REFCODE]

LEFT JOIN [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[USER_MASTER] ON [USER_MASTER].[USR_REFCODE] = [EVENT_PIC].[USR_REFCODE]

LEFT JOIN [CSEventDB2].[dbo].[PARTICIPANT_MASTER] ON [PARTICIPANT_MASTER].[PCPT_REFCODE] = [EVENT_SPEAKER].[PCPT_REFCODE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not return any value unless I excute  'print @strSpeaker' It also will return single value as is not concate the return value to local variable..

Comment: The value is set to blank so there's nothing to concatenate in your example but SQL doesn't have the += operator so you'd need to have something like "@strSpeaker = @strSpeaker + selectedvalue" to append like that.

Comment: yes is set to blank at first, but i need every record is pass to local variable with delimited coma, so it will have concatenate with previous value..can it be achieve with above query?